# What substances have the lowest dielectric strength (volts/meter)?

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials, material-science, semiconductor, insulator

All the tables of dielectric strength I can find are lists of materials that engineers use as practical insulators, and air is usually the least insulating thing on the list.

Where can I find a more comprehensive list of dielectric strengths, including for insulators that are "worse" than air? Are dielectric strength values in volts per meter physically defined for substances like iron that are usually modeled as "conductors"? If not, what materials have small but measurable dielectric strengths?

Comment: Have you got an application in mind or is this just a curiosity thing?

Comment: @Transistor I'm ultimately trying to do something like a three-element spark gap switch, or neon tube logic, but at lower voltages than are usually used because the sparks are happening in this magical terrible insulator.

Comment: Dielectric constant is based on permittivity of free space, so all insulation materials will be greater or equal to 1.

Comment: A chemical table listing all the elements.

Comment: Lowest? Do you mean a superconductor? For a conductor you might be able to get something theoretical via modeling a theoretically infinitely long material, or other approaching some condition curves.

Comment: CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics -- permittivity values. Also investigate how to change the geometry of the component to avoid sparks jumping over it.